# force a citrix desktop group when logging in from a particular workstation

Tags: citrix

I'm trying to find a way to force any user that logs into our Citrix XenDesktop environment from a particular workstation/thin client to log directly into a specified Desktop Group rather than be presented with a list of all desktop groups that user is entitled to.  Is this possible?